# Highcharts: remove all the spacing

Tags: highcharts

how can I remove all the spacing? except `margin` and `spacing`

Demo: http://jsbin.com/jukobenaso/edit?html,js,output

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNgft.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the chart's height is 200:

```
$('#chart').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    height: 200,
```

so you could set series size to 200 as well:

```
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      showInLegend: true,
      tooltip: {
        enable: false
      }
    },
    series: {
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      enableMouseTracking: false,
      size: 200,
      innerSize: '80%',
      center: [80, '50%']
    }
  },
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/kobunigami/edit?html,js,output